# Is there an alternative to js dom manipulation in angular 4?

Tags: angular, typescript, ngfor, dom-manipulation

I have this ngfor that loops a collection of 3 items:

```html
<ng-template ngFor let-person="$implicit" 
[ngForOf]="peopleAsPreviousCurrentAndNextTriplets" let-first="first">
  <app-card
    [class.currentCard] = "first" 
    [prevCard]          = "first ? person.previous : null" 
    [currentCard]       = "first ? person.current : null" 
    [nextCard]          = "first ? person.next : null"
   ></app-card>
</ng-template>
```

and if you check the dom, you'll see the following:

[image]

Now the idea was that I need to manipulate the above dom based on a button click, where:

1. The first `<app-card>` component is pushed to the last
2. The second `<app-card>` is pushed to the front
3. The last `<app-card>` is pushed to the second

I can do this very easy using js, but I hate the idea of dom manipulation directly. Is it possible to do it in `"angular 4"` approach.

Thanks

Comment: Well, yes. On click, rearrange the array (peopleAsPreviousCurrentAndNextTriplets) the way you like, and the template will display the elements in their new order. Not sure why you're using ngTemplate and not a simple *ngFor on app-card directly, BTW.

Comment: But if I manipulate the array directly, I wont be able to add any animation while the change happens in the view. Thats why I cant do that approach. Or can I? @JBNizet

Comment: Yes, you can, otherwise the whole idea of views reacting to changes in the model, which is the foundation principle of angular, would be ruined. Now don't ask me how to deal with angular animations: I know almost nothing about that. But if your question is about how to achieve a specific animation when reordering an array in a specific way, then ask *that* question, with the necessary details.

Comment: lol don't worry about that mate, i wont ask that. I was just unsure if it was possible. Anyways thanks for ur help. Just give your answer below, so i can accept ur help. :) Thanks bud! @JBNizet

Comment: Don't worry about that. Too lazy to formulate an answer. You can just delete your question.

Comment: lol. Kl, amazing guy ;) @JBNizet

Comment: The alternative is Renderer2 service. That's how it's done by Angular itself. It provides a necessary abstraction to make it work on server side, too.

Comment: https://github.com/valor-software/ng2-dragula  You might find this library interesting... BTW: I removed angularjs from tags for you. Since you're asking about Angular 4

Comment: What if you just reorder your array . ?
That would be the best way, you don't even touch the DOM